# Trouble with Generics and extends

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, extends

So I have some code that does:

```
abstract class Node< T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Node<T, N> >
{ ...
}
```

So am I right to say that when a type T is used in this Node object, the type T must have the property of being comparable? Also, the N extends Node just means that when type N is used in this Node object, N must be a Node that has the properties of T and N? Yeah, it sounds convoluted, but am I correct in my interpretation? Thanks!

Comment: This definition does not compile. Please update it as you're missing a closing bracket somewhere.

Comment: Just updated with edit. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It still does not compile.

Comment: `class Node< T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Node<T, N> >` is what you mean?

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't change anything since as it stands abstract is only defining my object as an abstract object.

Comment: @Chris there was an extra bracket after Comparable.

Comment: oh, I see. I didn't realize I had an extra bracket there. Thanks!

Comment: I have made the edit.

Comment: I wasn't sure you meant this because this is a un-instantiable type. It has a recursive definition which depends on its own generic type parameter, hence it crates an infinite recursion on the second type parameter... so this is useless and no concrete type can be made of it.

Comment: @Renato: `class IntNode extends Node<Integer, IntNode>`

Comment: Ah... sorry, I tried it within a method and it didn't work because types inside methods cannot be recursive...

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is right. But... I interpret that a Node is a node like a tree-node, right? Unfortunately it is a bad idea to use N for more that the current value like the type for children and for the parent.

```
abstract class Node<T extends Comparable<T>, N extends Node<T, N>> {
  private Set<N> children = new LinkedHashSet<N>();
  private N parent = null;
  private T nodeValue = null;
}
```

In this case you will have the problem that `Node<Integer,?>` is active for the **complete Tree**. Every node in the tree must contains only Integers because you recursievly force childrens and parents to only contain Integers!